# Python Regex convert matches to a dictionary

Tags: python, regex

```
text = "Bob|19|01012017"
pat = re.compile("(?P<name>.+)|.*|(?P<bday>.+)") #hopefully this regex is correct
result = pat.match(text)
d = result.groupdict()
print d
```

What I get for d is:

```
{'bday': None, 'name': 'Bob|19|01012017'}
```

What I want is:

```
{bday: "01012017", name: "Bob"}
```

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong? I only need two fields for dict so I didn't write the age part.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to escape `|` to match literally otherwise the pattern is interpreted as *or*:

```
text = "Bob|19|01012017"
pat = re.compile("(?P<name>.+)\|.*\|(?P<bday>.+)") 
result = pat.match(text)
d = result.groupdict()

d
# {'bday': '01012017', 'name': 'Bob'}
```

---

A quick test against `split` method on the speed:

```
text = "Bob|19|01012017"
pat = re.compile("(?P<name>.+)\|.*\|(?P<bday>.+)")
​
def regex_to_dict(texts, pat):
    return [pat.match(text).groupdict() for text in texts]

regex_to_dict([text], pat)
# [{'bday': '01012017', 'name': 'Bob'}]

def split_to_dict(texts):
    dd = []
    for text in texts:
        name, _, bday = text.split('|')
        dd.append({'bday': bday, 'name': name})
    return dd

split_to_dict([text])
# [{'bday': '01012017', 'name': 'Bob'}]

texts = [text] * 100000

%timeit regex_to_dict(texts, pat)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 119 ms per loop

%timeit split_to_dict(texts)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 58.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: OMG thank you. I didn't know | was taken. What does | mean in regex?

Comment: It means `or`, `blah|foo` matches `blah` or `foo` for instance.

Comment: Also side question: in terms of time complexity, is using this faster or is using string.split and then construct the dict faster?

Comment: I don't have much experience with the speed. But my first guess is `split`, if your string is as regular as you've shown.

Comment: I added a rough speed test. `split` is about twice faster than regex in this case.

Answer (score 1):

For such simple case you may use simple `str.split()` approach:

```
text = "Bob|19|01012017"
items = text.split('|')
d = {'bday': items[-1], 'name': items[0]}

print(d)
```

The output:

```
{'name': 'Bob', 'bday': '01012017'}
```